# What is the awesomium navigate code?

Tags: basic, awesomium

What I am asking is what is the code to get the Awesomium web frame element to load specific pages? For example, the default Microsoft WebBrowser Element uses WebBrowser.Navigate(variable). What is the Awesomium equivelant of this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. 
It’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. 
See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to simply load a given URL and grab the final/rendered HTML source of that page, check out [this sample console app project](https://github.com/dj-nitehawk/ThreadSafeAwesomium.Net) on github.

It has a class called `Browser` which is a simplified thread-safe wrapper class for using Awesomium like the `WebBrowser` control but in a headless/windowless environment. Shouldn't be that difficult to modify it for a UI environment.

You can use that class like so:

```
Browser.StartWebCore()
Dim B as new Browser()
Dim HTML as String = B.GetRenderedHTML("http://cnn.com")
B.Dispose()
Browser.StopWebCore()
```